# Enumerate all possible subsets such that all are of the same length which is maximum and each contains non-repeating elements?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, partitions

Given a list `lists`:

```
lists={{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}}, 
       {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}}, 
       {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}}, 
       {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, 
       {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}};
```

I would like to get the following results:

```
results={
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}}, 
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}}, 
{{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}}, 
{{{1, 2}, {3, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}}, 
{{{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 6}, {3, 5}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 3}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}}}, 
{{{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 5}, {4, 6}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}}
}
```

**Notice that** for every subsets (i.e. `results[[1]]`), there are no repeated elements (i.e. `{1, 2}`) and every subsets contains the maxmum elements.

When `lists={{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}`, we can easily have `results={{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}}}`. Here is the example code which seems only works for n=4:

```
n = 4; 
lists = Select[Subsets[Subsets[Range[n], {2}], {Length[Range[n]]/2}], 
   DuplicateFreeQ@*Catenate];

results = {};
res = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[lists], i++,
  AppendTo[results, SortBy[res, First]];
  res = {};
  AppendTo[res, lists[[i]]];
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[lists], j++,
   If[DisjointQ[lists[[i]], lists[[j]]],
     If[Length[res] <= 1,
         AppendTo[res, lists[[j]]];,
         If[DisjointQ[Flatten[res, 1], lists[[j]]], AppendTo[res, lists[[j]]];];
       ];
     ];
   ];
  ];
results = DeleteDuplicates[DeleteCases[results, {}]];
len = Length[results];
```

Questions:

- Is there a simple way to do the above task? How to do the above task for `n=6`?
- When `n` goes large, my code doesn't work (i.e. `n=8`, `len` should be 6240; see [A000438](https://oeis.org/A000438)). Is there a systematically way?

Thank you very much in advance! Any hints or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following takes around 10 seconds for `n=8` on my laptop:

```
(* the input list of lists *)
n = 8;
lists = Select[DuplicateFreeQ@*Catenate]@Subsets[Subsets[Range@n, {2}], {n/2}];

(* return the elements of list that are "compatible" with l*)
comp[l_, list_] := Select[DisjointQ[#, l] &]@list[[FirstPosition[list, l][[1]] + 1 ;;]]

(* recursively build the candidate subsets*)
build[rem_] := MaximalBy[Length]@Reap[build[l[], rem]][[2, 1]]
build[cur_, rem_] := (build[l[#, cur], comp[#, rem]] & /@ rem;)
build[cur_, {}] := Sow[List @@ Flatten@cur]

(* compute the result *)
res = build[lists];
Length@res
(* 6240 *)
```

This works by building up the subsets step-by-step, while trying to be somewhat clever about it:

- We keep track of the lists that we can still use, i.e. the lists that have no element in common with the previously used ones. This is handled by `comp` above. One important point is that we only consider elements coming after `l` to be compatible. This ensures that we are not double counting possibilities.
- We building up the valid lists, we hand down the list of compatible lists (That list will only get shorter at each step). If we can add any lists anymore, we [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) the list we have built up. At the end, we only keep those lists of maximal length.
- Instead of using `Append` or similar, we build a linked-list type structure that looks like `l[elem3, l[elem2, l[elem1, l[]]]]`. This is way more efficient, and we can get the final list using `Flatten`. Similarly, we use `Reap` and `Sow` to collect the result list, again since it is faster than using `Append`.

Comment: that's amazing! thank you so much!  btw, the ```res = Reap[build[l[], flists, n - 1]][[2, 1]];```, I think you mean ```res = Reap[build[l[], lists, n - 1]][[2, 1]];```. for side question, can you method work for lists which don't have the all elements such as ```lists={{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}}```?

Comment: @Xuemei Thanks, there was indeed a typo in that expression. With your side question: Do you mean whether it can find subsets that do not contain the maximum number of elements, or do you mean whether it can work when `lists` does not contain all possible elements?

Comment: thank you, I mean whether it works when ```lists``` does not contain all possible elements. Is that possiable? It can be connected to graph theory, such as ```gg = CycleGraph[6]; getpairs = EdgeList[gg] /. UndirectedEdge -> List; lists =Select[DuplicateFreeQ@*Catenate]@Subsets[getpairs, {Length[VertexList[gg]]/2}];``` Instead of ```gg=CompleteGraph[6]```.

Comment: @Xuemei Yes, the code should also work if `lists` contains only some of the elements. If you run into any issues, please let me know

Comment: If I make```lists={{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}}``` and ```n=6``` (correspond to ```gg=CycleGraph[6]```), I get some errors when it run to ```res = Reap[build[l[], lists, n - 1]][[2, 1]];```, which shows ```Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.```.

Comment: @Xuemei What exactly should it do in that case? The issue it is running into is that it doesn't find a combination of lists that is maximal. The `n-1` tells it to look for subsets of length `5` (which are needed to get a maximal subset for `n=6` which contains all $3\cdot 5=15$ elements). If you want to find subsets of length `2`, you can replace the `n-1` with `2`, i.e. `res = Reap[build[l[], lists, 2]][[2, 1]];`

Comment: Sorry for the bad example. let's say ```lists = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}}};```, I would expect something like ```res={{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}},{{{1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}}}}.``` It seems cannot directly use ```Length[lists]``` instead of ```n-1``` in general.

Comment: @Xuemei I have tweaked the code slightly, it should now be able to handle these cases better. For your last example, `build[lists]` gives only a single subset however (your first one does not seem valid, since both lists contain `{3,4}`).

Comment: yes, you are right. thank you for pointing out! I am very greatful for your nice help! thank you!